# Unity iPhone ARKit - NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, graphql

I am new to the world of Unity and C#. I am having trouble making network request to GraphQL endpoint. I am creating an AR app using **Unity ARKit** plugin. I am using https://github.com/carlflor/unity_graphql_client package to make a request. I get `NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required. at MyScript.Start () [0x00000]` Error while running the app on Xcode.

This code is from the package and that what causing the issue. Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

```js
public class SomeGameObject : MonoBehaviour {

  public APIClient api;

  void Start () {
    StartCoroutine (api.QueryCall( (bool success) => {
        if (success)
          Debug.Log( "success!");
        else
          Debug.Log( "fail!");
    }))
  }
}
```

NOTE: I am aware that the package has some misspelled variables. I have fixed everything and set up the endpoints and queries for my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't initialize your reference `api`. Debug your code if your references value is `null`, you need to initialize `api` before using it(i hope APIClient got a default constructor, so `api=new APIClient()` should be enought).

```
public class SomeGameObject : MonoBehaviour {

  public APIClient api/*=new APIClient()*/;

  void Start () {
    api= new APIClient();//its better to do it here in case its constructor does dark magic
    StartCoroutine (api.QueryCall( (bool success) => {
        if (success)
          Debug.Log( "success!");
        else
          Debug.Log( "fail!");
    }))
  }
}
```

check this for debugging with visual studio& unity: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio

I don't have an actual unityEditor instance open with visual studio for a good screenshot, however you should have a button on the pannel on screenshot below that says "connect to unity"(or something like this), add some breakpoints in visual studio near your variables(click on empty space on left of your row number in visual studio, red circle will apear and your execution will stop when you reach that row)
[image]

Comment: How do you check if reference is null? Could you give me a code snippet please.

Comment: i added a new section in my answer, sorry i don't have unity on current laptop, check the video i send, it explains you how to debug proprely.